# pyclbr cannot import classes from another directory?

Tags: python

This works fine if A.py and B.py are in the same directory

```
# module.py
class A(object):
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

# module2.py
import module
class C(module.B):
    pass
```

that works fine:

```
Python 2.7.8 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2014, 15:13:35) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>>> import pyclbr
>>> m = pyclbr.readmodule( "module2")
>>> m.items()[0][1].super
[<pyclbr.Class instance at 0x01EE61E8>]
```

but if I put module.py in, say, the foo directory and instead have:

```
# module2.py
import foo.module
class C(foo.module.B):
    pass
```

pyclbr cannot parse foo.module.B:

```
Python 2.7.8 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2014, 15:13:35) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>>> import pyclbr
>>> m = pyclbr.readmodule( "module2")
>>> m.items()[0][1].super
['foo.module.B']
```

Answer (score 0):

That's why you must create a empty `__init__.py` file in directory where python module is placed. i.e:

```
.
├── main.py
├── foo
|   ├── __init__.py
|   └── module2.py
```

So you import like this:

```
# main.py    
import foo.module2

pyclbr.readmodule("foo.module2.B")
```

Or pass second parameter to [pyclbr.readmodule(module, path=None)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pyclbr.html):

```
paths_lookup = ["foo", "other/path"] 
pyclbr.readmodule("module2", paths_lookup)
```

When passing a list of paths to pyclbr.readmodule does Python merge those with sys.path.
Anyway, just remember to create a `__init__.py` for each module directory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I already had an (empty) __ init __.py, and passing in ['.','foo'] doesn't make any difference.  pyclbr still returns foo.module.B is a string, not an object.

Comment: @DavidWorenklein Well... it work for me just like shown in the Python docs. Sure you're doing something wrong. Cheers!